# ui.bootstrap modal does not load modal content, it only shows backdrop

Tags: ui.bootstrap

The issue is for the fist time only other times it works fine. When i tried to open modal as below.Some times the modal content which tied to templateUrl is not rendered, it only shows backdrop with out modal content.I am using angular-ui-bootstrap version Version: 2.4.0. Kindly help me in finding the issue. The issue is rarely reproduced not all the times.

```
dialog = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            scope: scope,
            size: "lg",
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            templateUrl: 'question.html',
            windowClass: 'ep-std-dialog-position'
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Did anyone face same kind of issue ? Its happening sometimes on first load of modal after we keep the browser ideal for sometime.

Comment: The issue is resolved . Thanks.